# What's the difference between cookie-session and JWT tokens?

Tags: javascript, web, session, jwt, cookie-session

This library here stores your session data on the client https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session. But doesn't that make it a JWT token (as opposed to a "session")?

Is the difference that cookie-session stores the data in cookies, versus JWT tokens are usually stored in localStorage?

Just confused about terminology here, thanks.

Comment: *JWT tokens are usually stored in localStorage* is an assumption - what makes you say that? - there's a big difference between how using a session vs using JWT works - which part don't you understand?